# Is it possible to define a GET to not return either the id, index, type and/or score from the ES datastore?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

When doing a GET from my datastore, I get `_id`, `_index_`, `_type` and `_score` returned in the `body.hits.hits` but only want the data inside of the `_source`

For example:

```
[
    {
      "_index": "first-entry",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "IRQf0nkBaWzRmI7XDody",
      "_score": 0.2876821,
      "_source": {
          "Hello": "World!"
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "first-entry",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "IhQr0nkBaWzRmI7XZIeC",
      "_score": 0.2876821,
      "_source": {
          "Hello": "world!"
      }
    }
]
```

Is there a way to filter this information out or just exclude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) to that purpose:

```
GET index/_doc/123?filter_path=hits.hits._source
```

Comment: So to do this in JS, do you just use a ``filter_path`` field and specify the hits.hits._source?

Comment: Yes, that's just another URL query string parameter

Comment: Is it possible you could give a quick example in JS? I'm struggling to get the filter_path to return just the ``_source`` as mentioned

Comment: See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_common_parameters)